# Solving an 2nd order ODE (missing $x$) with a method used for solving ODEs with $x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have the following equation

$$2yy'' - 3y'^2 -4y^2 =0$$

I have been taught that, if we encounter these ODEs with $x$ missing, we should introduce the substitution:

$y' = p(y)$, $y'' = p'p$ and so forth.

Now, there's also a method for solving ODEs (**that do have the variable x**) which involves checking if the ODE is homogenous for $y$ and its derivatives. If it is, we can do the following substitution:

$y=e^{\int zdx}$, where $y' = yz$, and $y'' = y(z^2+z')$

My question is: Can I use this method for my ODE (it doesn't have $x$?)

I tried it, and here's what I got:

$$2y^2 (z^2+z') - 3y^2z^2 - 4y^2 =0$$

$$-z^2 + 2z' - 4 =0$$

$$z=2\arctan{(x+c_1)}$$

Now, in order to get the solution I'd have to do

$$y=e^{\int{2\arctan{(x+c_1)}}}$$

and the integral is $$\int{\arctan{(x+c_1)}} = (x+c_1)\arctan{(x+c_1)} - \frac{\ln{((x+c_1)^2+1)}}{2} $$

If I set this to be an exponent of $e$, the result wouldn't be pretty. However, the WolframAlpha solution is $$c_2 \sec^2(c_1+x)$$

Can I use the method designed for homogenous (w.r.t $y$ and its derivatives) ODEs, which **do** contain $x$, for an ODE which is homogenous w.r.t. $y$ and its derivatives, but does not contain $x$?

Comment: Can you give some reference about that $y' = p(y)$ and so on?

Comment: @ArcticChar I'm not sure what you mean by reference, but I think that it's a common way of solving autonomous ODEs. Since they don't explicitly contain the dependent variable, we can let that $y' = p$, $p=p(y)$. After performing a derivation, and applying the chain rule, we get that $y'' = p'p$. 

Article on WolframAlpha: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Autonomous.html

Comment: You got the function inversion the inverse way. $z$ is the tangent with some decorations, the arcus tangent occurs during the implicit integration where you get $x+c$ on the right side.

Answer (score 1):

You correctly got to $$2z'=z^2+4.$$ Then you jumped over the ensuing separation-of-variables formalism
$$
\int\frac{2dz}{z^2+4}=\int dx,\\
\arctan\frac z2=x+c.
$$
For some reason you then put the inverse of the arcus tangent as the arcus tangent, while correctly you should get in the next step
$$
z=2\tan(x+c).
$$
With that you then quickly get the same as the reference result.

Comment: Oh I see now. My concentration must have slipped. Thanks!